# Updates were rejected error while trying to keep two git repos in-sync using gitlab CI

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using gitlab CI to keep my codebase in two different gitlab deployments in synch. I would like to only push to one gitlab deployment and then have that CI automatically push to the second gitlab deployment.

In order to do this I added login in my `.gitlab-ci.yml`, however, while pushing to the second gitlab deployment I get errors:

```
$ git pull origin master
From https://gitlab.firstdeployment.com/MYGROUP/myrepo
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
$ git pull seconddeployment master
From gitlab.seconddeployment.com:MYGROUP/myrepo.git
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      master     -> io/master
Already up-to-date.
$ git status
HEAD detached at 6e8093e
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ git push io master
To gitlab.seconddeployment.com:MYGROUP/myrepo.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'gitlab.seconddeployment.com:MYGROUP/myrepo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I understand I could use the `push -f` forcefully, however, I don't understand why I'm getting this error from the CI when I'm doing a proper `pull`

Comment: `git status` says you're in a detached HEAD state, are you sure `git pull` did what you wanted? Try `git checkout master` and then `git pull`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen are you recommending I do `git checkout master` after `git pull origin master` or `git pull seconddeployment master` ?